# Can't start Apache - Address already in use - httpd is stopped

Tags: apache-2.2, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

I'm trying to set up an Amazon EC2 web server on the "Virtual Private Cloud". I'm using this instead of a standard EC2 instance because I needed to assign multiple public IPs and that necessitates the use of VPC.

Anyway, after much hoop jumping, I finally got the instance up and running and connected via SSH. I built the instance from an image I took of a standard webserver that is working fine. However, I don't appear to be able to start Apache:

```
# service httpd status
httpd is stopped
# service httpd start
Starting httpd: (98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
(98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs
                                                           [FAILED]
# netstat -ltnp
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address               Foreign Address             State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22                  0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      1243/sshd
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      1275/sendmail
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9306                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      1225/searchd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9312                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      1225/searchd
tcp        0      0 :::80                       :::*                        LISTEN      1289/httpd
tcp        0      0 :::22                       :::*                        LISTEN      1243/sshd
tcp        0      0 :::443                      :::*                        LISTEN      1289/httpd
# ps aux | grep httpd
root      1287  0.0  0.2 108476  1780 ?        S    21:17   0:00 /bin/bash /etc/rc3.d/S85httpd start
root      1288  0.0  0.2  11348  1332 ?        S    21:17   0:00 /bin/bash -c ulimit -S -c 0 >/dev/null 2>&1 ; /usr/sbin/httpd
root      1289  0.0  1.2 211888  7764 ?        S    21:17   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
```

So I'm a bit confused. Apache isn't running (as a service, and I've not set it to run any other ways), and I can't start the service, but isn't this saying that Apache IS running? Any ideas how to resolve?

**Added 04/Dec/2012**

Apache has been installed and set to start automatically on boot with `chkconfig --levels 235 httpd on`, which is why the httpd process is running on boot. However, when you enter `service httpd status` it was still reading as stopped and was unavailable through a web browser.

In order to actually restart Apache, it appears that you need to kill the process gracefully (`kill -15 1289` works, where 1289 was the process ID) and then enter `service httpd start`. You can now start, stop, restart and reload Apache with no problem.

However, I wanted to be able to use the service command immediately, and further poking around led me to a conclusion that nobody could've realistically provided: One of the SSL keys requires a passphrase, and it couldn't be entered at boot (clearly), so the process was unable to start properly. I removed the passphrase (that we didn't really want, anyway) and rebooted. Now, when I check with `service httpd status` I get `httpd dead but subsys locked`. I have to delete `/var/lock/subsys/httpd` to get the process to start correctly again.

So, it felt like progress, but the process still doesn't start automatically.

Ideas, please?

Comment: Yes, it's saying Apache is running, because it is. Kill those processes and then restart it again, it should work.

Comment: OK, apparently someone thinks "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful". I accept that maybe it was a little unclear in that I'd originally stated that Apache was not running when clearly it is. What I meant was that it's not running as a service, which is how it was configured to run, so I don't understand how it's running or why. Yes, I killed the processes and that allowed me to start the service, but I don't understand why it's started already. Nor do I understand why it's like this every reboot. Any help?

Comment: What struck me is that last three lines of the netstat result. In the AWS VPC Security Group, I have only allowed four TCP ports: 22, 80, 443 and 3306. MySQL isn't yet installed, so I'm not surprised to not see it in the list. Seeing httpd and sshd holding those particular ports leads me to believe that it's probably the AWS platform itself that's doing this, but only via VPC and not standard EC2 instances?

Comment: AWS isn't doing anything.  If the machine is listening on 22, it's because sshd is running, and we know Apache is running from your `ps aux` so that's likely what is causing 80 and 443.  There are two sides  here: the firewall (security group) associated with the instance, and then which ports are being opened by services on your machine.

Comment: Oh and to answer your second comment, apache and ssh are starting on reboot because they are set to do so in in `/etc/init.d` scripts.  Depending on your distro, there are commands you can use to determine what starts on reboot -- `chkconfig` on CentOS and RHEL, for example.  Apache will start and use the configuration specified under `/etc/httpd` in files like `httpd.conf` and others.

Comment: OK, appreciate that. Maybe if I explain why I find it unusual? We set this up as a standard EC2 instance and when you start it and do a service httpd status you will see Apache is running. We created the VPC EC2 instance from a snapshot of this machine and the behaviour is now different. Now the service isn't running, but Apache is. That's why I'm confused. Why two identical images are behaving differently depending on whether they're standard EC2 or running in a VPC

Comment: I now realise why they're running differently. If you notice my edit in the original question, it's because I've now installed the SSL certificates on two of the VHosts and one requires a passkey. I've now removed that

Answer (score 3):

> tcp   0   0 :::80   :::*    LISTEN      1289/httpd

Httpd is running, and has a process id of 1289.  If for some unusual reason that isn't Apache and something else that is also named httpd, then you might be able to find more information with a command like `lsof -n -p 1289`.

You could probably just `kill` that process though.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It is running, but isn't working, if you see what I mean? It's not accepting incoming requests. I have killed it and started it manually and it works fine. Turns out that it's because of a passphrased SSL certificate, but removing the passphrase just introduces a new fault. I've edited the original to elaborate further

Answer (score 1):

I'd say apache IS running, and you can see it in the display....netstat indicates that process 1289 is listening on port 80 and indeed the ps is showing this too.  httpd is apache!

Thus you probably can simply kill -9 1289 (as root) and then restart.